# How to download video from a paid course without any download link? Any way via inspect element? I am not an expert

Tags: web, url, video, download, find

course-chapter-detail/62e773a518c8e105da8c9fe4/62e7740818c8e105ddf408d4/
after the name of the company, it has this written,

How to download the video? I have paid for the course.

Comment: File could also be encrypted so don't get hopeful. I suspect you paid for the course but not the right to distribute copies to other people. What will you do when someone offers you some money for a copy of the file? It will be tempting to sell a copy... Just study it on their website or player and be finished.